# Difference in memory layout of pointer to base and pointer to derived object

Tags: c++, inheritance

If I have the following classes:

```
class A
{
public:
  A(int val) : m_valA(val) {}

private:
   int m_valA;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  B(int val) : A(0), m_valB(val) {}

private:
  int m_valB;
};


    B* pb = new B;
```

if I have a function which takes a A*, eg:

```
void func(A* pVal) {}
```

and pb is passed to this function, then in terms of low level memory layout, what is the difference between pval (in the function) and the pb pointer?

Doesn't a pointer point to the beginning of the object?  In which case how will the two pointers be different?

Comment: if you didn't forget some additional ancestors or virtual functions.. for single inheritance of non-polimorphic classes the pointers are  _usually_ the same (although it is not guaranted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesn't a pointer point to the beginning of the object? In which case how will the two pointers be different?

If you pass a pointer to a `B` object to `func(A* pVal)`, then inside the `func()` implementation the `pVal` pointer will point to the `A` sub-object part of the `B` object.  It's unspecified whether they will be at the same location (though for a simple inheritance situation as in your example, it almost certainly will be).

If the `A` sub-object is actually at a different offset (which might need to be the case if multiple inheritance is involved, for example), then the compiler will make the appropriate adjustment automatically when it compiles the call.  The compiler can do this because at the call site it knows it's dealing with a `B*` and needs to convert it to an `A*` to pass to `func()`.  That's a safe and normal conversion since `B` publicly inherits from `A`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void func(A* pVal) {}
```

`pb` is upcasted to `pVal`. It points to the base class sub-object. However, if it is a polymorphic class, it calls the overridden derived class methods if virtual.

`pb` can access both the sub-objects members depending upon access level. However, `pVal` access only the base class sub-object members. However run-time polymorphism is possible if the base class is polymorphic.