# If I convert a derived pointer to a base pointer, are the two pointers guaranteed to have the same value?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Assuming that I'm not using multiple inheritance or virtual inheritance, does the C++ standard guarantee that if I convert a `Derived*` to a `Base*` that both pointers will have exactly the same value? For instance, will the following code always call `success()`, even if `Derived` and/or `Base` have virtual functions?

```
Derived* d = new Derived;
Base* b = d;
if (((void*)b) == ((void*)d)) 
    success();
else
    failure();
```

Comment: According to this, the raw pointers are not guaranteed to be the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943892/difference-in-memory-layout-of-pointer-to-base-and-pointer-to-derived-object

Comment: The pointers may be equal initially, but what happens if someone goes in later and does some maintenance on the code, and they no longer are equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the base class has no virtual functions and the derived class does, the pointers would likely be different because the base class wouldn't have the vtable pointer present in the `D` object.